# Does parent table get locked when DDL operation happens on a child table?

Tags: oracle, locking, ddl

Consider this DB table structure:

table1 {col1, col2, col3}

table2 {col5, col2, col6}

Col2 is the PK of table1 and it is the foreign key in the table2 - referential integrity constraint exists in table2 on col2. but col2 is NOT indexed in table2.

Now, i issue a DDL operation to drop column col6 from table2.

**Issue**: other applications accessing table1 died since they were NOT able to *Insert* into table1 because a lock was acquired on this table.

**Question**: Does DDL operation on table2 with just a foreign key constraint acquire exclusive lock on table1??

I am not able to find any information on the web related to this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: logically, yes it should be.

Comment: It might lock as dropping column leads to physical updating data in blocks. Anyway it's better to check:
SELECT 
   a.sid
 , a.serial#
 , a.username
 , c.os_user_name
 , a.program
 , a.logon_time
 , a.machine
 , a.terminal
 , b.object_id
 , substr(b.object_name,1,40) object_name
 , DECODE(c.locked_mode,
 1, 'No Lock',
 2, 'Row Share',
 3, 'Row Exclusive',
 4, 'Shared Table',
 5, 'Shared Row Exclusive',
 6, 'Exclusive') locked_mode
from v$session a
 , dba_objects b
 , v$locked_object c
where a.sid = c.session_id
 and b.object_id = c.object_id;

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT1351) Only individual schema objects that are modified or referenced are locked during DDL operations.

There are often weird cases involving DDL, but in this case there doesn't appear to be any blocking issues.  For example, the loops below can run at the same time without causing errors.  If you can reproduce your error with a test case similar to the one below we should be able to find the problem.

**Sample Schema**

```
drop table table2;
drop table table1;

create table table1(col1 number, col2 number primary key, col3 number);
create table table2(col5 number, col2 number, col6 number,
    constraint table2_fk foreign key (col2) references table1(col2));

insert into table1 values(1,1,1);
insert into table1 values(2,2,2);
insert into table2 values(1,1,1);
commit;
```

**Session 1 - Modify parent, no exceptions**

```
begin
    loop
        delete from table1 where col2 = 2;
        insert into table1 values(3,3,3);
        rollback;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

**Session 2 - Modify child - exceptions are expected and are ignored**

```
begin
    loop
        execute immediate 'alter table table2 drop column col6';
        execute immediate 'alter table table2 add (col6 number)';
    end loop;
end;
/
```